# Spam question title still showing up in the <title> tag

Tags: bug, question-titles

The following question was flagged as spam and promptly deleted:

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/626807 (only visible to 10k users)

The title displayed on the page states that:

> "This question was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown"

That's all fine and well, but the question title is still shown in the browser's titlebar:

[image]

Now, the title of this question is hardly offensive - but suppose that it were. I assume that the message displayed on the page in place of the title exists to keep users from seeing words/phrases that they'd rather not see.

Therefore it only makes sense that the contents of the `<title>` tag should similarly be replaced with the message.

Comment: I think this counts as a limited edge case - as only 10k plus users, and also diamond moderators and SE employees/engineers, can see deleted items is this really a huge concern?

Comment: @ThomasW. yes it is! >:-D

Comment: @ThomasW. My reasoning is that if it was a large enough concern to display the message on the page, it's a large enough concern to display the message in the title.

Comment: @NathanOsman Cross site dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256815/obfuscate-spam-in-page-title-as-well